# Drive 24V Lamps. Will this circuit work?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I made a circuit to read the data from a ultrasonic sensor and drive two 24V lamps. Will this circuit work? **The relay ALREADY has a flyback diode.**

Am I missing something or it's all good?

[image]

Comment: Looks right to me. Have you tried building it?

Comment: not yet. I want to make sure before I do.

Comment: The relays will switch fine, I can tell you that much. You'll be drawing about 4.3~4.5mA out of each output pin, though; double check that your model of arduino is capable of that.

Comment: At least, the relays will switch fine if they're rated to switch at 5V on the coils. Some relays need 12V or still different coil voltages.

Comment: looks like you need a flyback diode in there /s

Answer (score 3):

What you show might be OK, except that there must be flyback diodes in reverse across the relay coils.

No, it's not good enough to just mention this in the text.  You *must* show such things in the schematic too.  Don't be so lazy.

You should also check whether the transistors can support the full relay coil current.  Apparently your digital outputs will be at 5 V when high.  That puts about 4.3 mA into a transistor base.  Let's say these transistors can be counted on to have a gain of 50 at that operating point (just making up something, your job to check the datasheet), then the maximum supported relay coil current is 215 mA.  Of course it would be good to stay somewhat below that.  Small relays that can switch well beyond the kind of load you show are available with about 60 mA coil current at 5 V, so that all sounds reasonable.

Again, check the transistor and relay datasheets to make sure the above assumptions are valid.

Comment: are you there??